# Why Does Safari's CSS Positioning Break At Smaller Screen Widths

Tags: html, css, safari

On my site, www.azletconsulting.com, when the site drops below 950px safari breaks the positioning of the Register to Vote, Join the Campaign etc menu positioning. At the larger sizes everything is aligned properly but as soon as it drops to one of the smaller css media queries the menu buttons break alignment. The code is the same between all the media queries and I have no issue in Chrome/Firefox.

```
.main_footer_menu {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 319px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(93, 93, 93, 1);
    z-index: 10;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul#menu-bottom-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
}

li#menu-item-28 a {
    left: -200px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80.5px;
    background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/rov.png");
    background-size: 200px 80.5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-indent: -99999999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li#menu-item-29 a {
    top: -90px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80.5px;
    background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/join.png");
    background-size: 200px 80.5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-indent: -99999999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li#menu-item-30 a {
    top: -175px;
    left: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80.5px;
    background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/contribute.png");
    background-size: 200px 80.5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-indent: -99999999px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.main_footer_menu {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 319px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(93, 93, 93, 1);
    z-index: 10;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    ul#menu-bottom-menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 80px;
    }

    li#menu-item-28, li#menu-item-29, li#menu-item-30 {
        display: inline-block;
    }

        li#menu-item-28 a, li#menu-item-29 a, li#menu-item-30 a {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            height: 80.5px;
            background-size: 200px 80.5px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            text-indent: -99999999px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        li#menu-item-28 a {
            background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/rov.png");
        }


        li#menu-item-29 a {
            background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/join.png");
        }

        li#menu-item-30 a {
            background-image: url("images/buttons/medium/contribute.png");
        }
```

Comment: Hey that totally fixed the issue thanks so much! Can you explain what was wrong with the was I was doing it previously?

Comment: @Baroti it's simple case, you don't need `position: relative` with `top` and `left` for `li a` elements, it's superfluous. And you need `display: inline-block` for `li` items to place it in a row.